# Is there a Sybase equivalent to the SQL Server / Oracle WITH keyword?

Tags: sql, sybase

In Oracle / SQL Server I can use the WITH keyword to define a transient table for use in views:

```
WITH a AS (SELECT something_horrible FROM somewhere_horrible)
SELECT * FROM a
```

Very handy when the 'table' a may be used many times in the query. I think there are performance gains when the SELECT for a is convoluted (I think it's usually only executed once).

Is there an equivalent in Sybase?

(NB I know there are temp tables, but I am trying to write VIEWs, hence no syntax to create / use the temp table)

Thanks in advance

Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Sybase supports CTEs. So you can use both WITH and WITH RECURSIVE keywords

Comment: Thank you. A search for 'Comon Table Expressions' reveals http://dcx.sybase.com/1100/en/dbusage_en11/commontblexpr-s-5414852.html which is useful

Answer (score 0):

How about this technique:

```
SELECT h.* FROM
    (SELECT something_horrible FROM somewhere_horrible) h
```

Comment: A subselect is not the same as a transient table, because it can not be reused.

Comment: That's what I end up doing - a lot! However as @phlogratos points out, the horrible_select may be executed more than once - depends on the execution plan I guess. And if something _horrible is 30 lines of SQL, re-used, it gets pretty messy quite quickly...